# Applying armature removes weighted vertex/armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, normals, unity, pose-mode

I have a problem with a model I made. I made the model, imported it to unity, and everything was fine. The normals are like they should be.
Then i went into blender and added a armature to the mesh. I then parented the mesh to the armature.   In pose mode, i can move the mesh with the bones. BUT, now in unity, my normals are all flipped.

Then In Blender, I found out that under "modifier tab", I had not applied the armature, so I went and did that. Now the normals are fine again in unity, but my mesh wont follow the armature in pose mode anymore.  And all the vertex weight groups are also gone.

What am i doing wrong?

Sincerely, Thomas

Comment: Not at all an expert in this area, but I don't think you are supposed to apply the armature modifier to the mesh. That would make it static

Comment: But if i don't, the faces all go haywire in unity.

Comment: Yeah but haywire faces can theoretically be fixed, weather it is a bug or an issue with your model; whereas a static mesh is ultimately useless, I am guessing

Comment: Differently than others 3D softwares, in Blender "applying" the armature means set all the vertices in the new positions as moved by the bones, permanently, and remove the armature. When you apply the armature, the mesh still mantains all vertex groups named as the deformig bones and correctly weighted: if you create a bone with the right name and assign the new armature modifier in the modifiers stack, it will work. You should search for the reason why the normals are inverted in Unity, which should be an Unity problem.

Comment: Actually, I think i found an answer.   I marked my character and applied it's location, scale, and rotation to "3D cursor" at center, and then made the armature.  And it works now. But thanks anyway, I did learn something or two :)
It must have been something about the mirroring on negative scale ?
All my normals had to be flipped once I did that.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think i found an answer. I marked my character and applied it's location, scale, and rotation to "3D cursor" at center, and then made the armature. And it works now. But thanks anyway, I did learn something or two :) It must have been something about the mirroring on negative scale ? All my normals had to be flipped once I did that. Have a nice day!